# How to update value of unique key in nested dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say that we have this `dict`:

```
{
  "app_url": "",
  "models": [
    {
      "perms": {
        "add": true,
        "change": true,
        "delete": true
      },
      "add_url": "/admin/cms/news/add/",
      "admin_url": "/admin/cms/news/",
      "name1": ""
    }
  ],
  "has_module_perms": true,
  "name2": "u\u0027CMS\u0027"
}
```

How to set a new value for the key `add_url` if the requirement is to only provide the key and the value?

So i don't want to do something like `data["models"]["add_url"] = value` but instead i'd like to pass only `"add_url"` and the new value to a function.

In my case every key in the `dict` is a unique `str` so that it can't happen that a key appears more then once.

Comment: I see two keys named by "name". Are you sure it will be unique?

Comment: @NitinPawar those keys are in different dicts. Key unicity is a builtin contraint of dicts and is actually part of the definition of what a dict is.

Comment: @NitinPawar i changed it. That was not a good example. Every key will be unique, yes

Comment: @Endogen I'm afraid you have no other option than using `data["models"][x]["add_url"] = value`. You can wrap this in a function taking the relevant dict, value etc but in the end you will have to set the value.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers True, but since i only want to provide the key-name and new value, you can't be sure which key-value should be updated so it's necessary that the key is unique and i my case, it is.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers I'm fine with setting that value like that but i don't want to do it myself. If the function does it that i pass the arguments to, it's fine. So if the function builds that up, ok

Comment: What do you mean by "(not) doing  it by yourself" ? Wether you encapsulate this in a function or do it directly doesn't make any difference, and in both cases you'll need the dict, the index of the subdict you want to update (`data["models"]` is a list of dicts), the key you want to set and the value - you cannot expect the function to work with only the key and value.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers Of course but i will have to set different values for different keys in different places in the code and i don't want to care about the correct "path". i just want the function to do it for me. I don't want to hardcode the "path". The function whould derive the path dynamically.

Comment: I'm afraid python functions don't have grown mind-reading abilities yet, so I fail to imagine how the function would work without being given the correct path one way or another. And I very strongly advise you against any "try and guess" approach (like recursively visiting the dict and it's values until a seemingly match key is found), this is garanteed to break one way or another, leading to logical errors, incorrect results, eventually corrupted data without any warning.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers Please see belthazorNv answer. That's what i need - mind-reading abilities needed

Comment: @Endogen I saw this answer and this is most definitlty what you should NOT be doing (been here, done that, thought I was quite smart, now I know better). But if you really want to go this route well your choice, you will positively LOVE debugging this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to find the field and update the value.

```
your_dict = {
  "app_url": "",
  "models": [
    {
      "perms": {
        "add": True,
        "change": True,
        "delete": True
      },
      "add_url": "/admin/cms/news/add/",
      "admin_url": "/admin/cms/news/",
      "name1": ""
    }
  ],
  "has_module_perms": True,
  "name2": "u\u0027CMS\u0027"
}

def recursive_update(haystack, needle, value):
  if isinstance(haystack, dict):
    for key, value_dict in haystack.items():
      if needle == key:
        haystack[key] = value
      elif isinstance(value_dict, list) or isinstance(value_dict, dict):
          recursive_update(value_dict, needle, value)
  elif isinstance(haystack, list):
    for value_list in haystack:
      if isinstance(value_list, dict):
        recursive_update(value_list, needle, value)

  return haystack
```

**Usage:**

```
recursive_update(your_dict, 'add_url', 'http://www.google.com')
```

*Note: I don't recommend you using an implicit approach towards programming.*

The above is not thoroughly tested, so make sure to test it out; it's more of an example of how recursion can work towards achieving your goal.

Comment: hint; do NOT do this. This is the best way to get  corrupted data without any warning. Python Zen #11 : "in the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess".

Comment: The function doesn't guess. I can guarantee that every key is unique. Will use it :-)

Comment: @belthazorNv That's exactly what i wanted, thanks! Will look into it to make sure that it works in every case possible.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't like to do something as ambiguous and implicit as this, although yes, there are cases that you're cornered and have to. - I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I understand your perspective; as I've been in many difficult situations with ambiguity and implicitly guessing what you'll need in the future; but I'm curious actually; can you provide me with an alternative?